# Error Applying Security: Failed to enumerate object container

Tags: windows, windows-8

I just did a fresh install of Windows 8, and now trying to clean up my second drive. I am running into permission issues when I try to delete, or move a folder. Since I figured it has something to do with ownership, I attempt to take ownership of the whole drive, and get the permissions to be inherited by everything.

However, I get the following error:

> Failed to enumerate object container

Answer (score 2):

A **Similar** issue in a similar situation is discussed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/438567/cant-delete-old-windows-directory) basically a **delete-privilege issue**.

The solution offered is to install [**unlocker**](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to do the deletion, or to use [**boot delete**](http://software.bootblock.co.uk/?id=bootdeleter) to schedule deletion on reboot.

As for taking ownership, it appears that **per-file is possible**, atleast according to that post. If this is so, maybe a script is doable?

edit: I have no experience with PowerShell, but someone seems to have tackled this very problem by a [powershell script here](http://www.definit.co.uk/2012/02/powershell-recursively-taking-ownership-of-files-and-folders-and-adding-permissions-without-removing-existing-permissions/). This might solve the larger issue.